# SQL alchemy instrumental list's order not saving

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, socket.io

I'm trying to update the order of a list of a chatrooms a user has by removing it and reinserting it at index 0 (and works), but when I reload my webpage and check, the order hasn't been saved even though I'm committing the database.
Here's my code:

Class Code:

```
user_chatroom_association = database.Table('user_chatroom_association',
                                       database.Column('user_id', database.Integer,
                                                       database.ForeignKey('users.id')),
                                       database.Column('chatroom_id', database.Integer,
                                                       database.ForeignKey('chatroom.id'))
                                       )


class Users(database.Model):
    id = database.Column("id", database.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = database.Column(database.String(100))
    email = database.Column(database.String(100))
    password = database.Column(database.String(100))

courses = database.Column(database.JSON)
chatrooms = database.relationship('Chatroom', secondary=user_chatroom_association, back_populates='users')

def __init__(self, name, email, password, courses):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.courses = courses

def add_chatroom(self, chatroom):
    current_rooms = self.chatrooms
    if chatroom in self.chatrooms:
        print("Chatroom already in User class")
        current_rooms.remove(chatroom)
    current_rooms.insert(0, chatroom)
    self.chatrooms = current_rooms
    database.session.commit()

def get_friends(self):
    friends = []
    for chatroom in self.chatrooms:
        friends.append(chatroom.get_friend(self))

    return friends

def add_friend(self, friend, commonality):
    chatroom = Chatroom(self.id, friend.id, commonality)
    self.add_chatroom(chatroom)
    friend.add_chatroom(chatroom)

    database.session.add(chatroom)

@staticmethod
def get_user(email=None, id=None):
    if email:
        return Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if id:
        return Users.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
```

The function in question is add_chatroom() in the Users class.
Here's my application of it:

```
@socketio.on('send_message')
```

def handle_send_message(data):
# get sender, receiver, and chatroom information
sender_email = flask.session.get("email")
sender = Users.get_user(email=sender_email)  # get sender from their email
sender_id = sender.id
receiver_id = data["user_id"]
receiver = Users.get_user(id=receiver_id)
room = Chatroom.get_chatroom(sender_id, receiver_id)

```
# add message to database
message = Message(sender.id, data["message"], chatroom=room)
database.session.add(message)
room.messages.append(message)

# Commit the message addition to the database
database.session.commit()

print(sender.chatrooms)

sender.add_chatroom(room)

print(sender.chatrooms)

# Move messages to the top and commit again
database.session.commit()
sender = Users.get_user(email=sender_email)
```

It works when I run the function but when I reload the page it reverts back to its original order.
Does anyone know why and any solutions?

Comment: Database tables don't have an intrinsic order. If you want to be able to retrieve rows in a particular order you need to be express that order in terms of the columns in the table. For example, if you want to retrieve chatrooms in the order that they have been accessed, you need a `last_accessed` column in the table that you can use to order your queries.

Comment: In addition to what @snakecharmerb said, you can add `order_by="Chatroom.last_accessed.desc()"` to your chatrooms relationship to have a default ordering in all your queries.